# After Adding Zoom Meeting SDK, BottomNavigationView is Crashing the app. Why this happening?

Tags: android, material-design, bottomnavigationview, material-components-android, zoom-sdk

After Adding zoom sdk BottomNavigationView is crashing.

[ZoomSDKImlementation][1] https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/sdk/native-sdks/android/build-an-app/

Here I found the problem with menu. If I removed app:menu error will gone, But menu is needed for sure.

`api 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'`

Issue from Xml Design Tab

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_nav_item_colors"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_nav_item_colors"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="selected"
        app:menu="@menu/calf_bottom_navigation" />
```

```
    at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationBarItemView.<init>(NavigationBarItemView.java:107)
    at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationItemView.<init>(BottomNavigationItemView.java:34)
    at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationMenuView.createNavigationBarItemView(BottomNavigationMenuView.java:197)
    at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationBarMenuView.getNewItem(NavigationBarMenuView.java:492)
    at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationBarMenuView.buildMenuView(NavigationBarMenuView.java:421)
    at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationBarPresenter.updateMenuView(NavigationBarPresenter.java:72)
    at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationBarView.inflateMenu(NavigationBarView.java:358)
    at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationBarView.<init>(NavigationBarView.java:226)
    at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView.<init>(BottomNavigationView.java:103)
    at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView.<init>(BottomNavigationView.java:98)
    at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView.<init>(BottomNavigationView.java:93)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:399)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:189)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:147)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:303)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:417)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:428)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:332)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1121)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1095)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:499)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:353)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:431)
    at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:141)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:714)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$7(RenderTask.java:870)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$runAsyncActionWithTimeout$2.run(RenderExecutor.kt:187)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Stacktrace when run the app

````
2022-02-17 16:24:16.909 6448-6448/com.lakshya.academy E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.lakshya.academy, PID: 6448
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.lakshya.academy/com.nuveda.calf.ui.participant.activity.ParticipantHomeActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #115: Binary XML file line #115: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #115: Binary XML file line #115: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #115: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:699)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
        at com.nuveda.calf.ui.participant.activity.ParticipantHomeActivity.onCreate(ParticipantHomeActivity.kt:82)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.ViewGroup.getPaddingBottom()' on a null object reference
        at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationBarItemView.<init>(NavigationBarItemView.java:107)
        at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationItemView.<init>(BottomNavigationItemView.java:34)
        at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationMenuView.createNavigationBarItemView(BottomNavigationMenuView.java:197)
        at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationBarMenuView.getNewItem(NavigationBarMenuView.java:492)
        at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationBarMenuView.buildMenuView(NavigationBarMenuView.java:421)
2022-02-17 16:24:16.910 6448-6448/com.lakshya.academy E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationBarPresenter.updateMenuView(NavigationBarPresenter.java:72)
        at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationBarView.inflateMenu(NavigationBarView.java:358)
        at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationBarView.<init>(NavigationBarView.java:226)
        at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView.<init>(BottomNavigationView.java:103)
        at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView.<init>(BottomNavigationView.java:98)
        at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView.<init>(BottomNavigationView.java:93)```


  [1]: https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/sdk/native-sdks/android/build-an-app
````

Comment: Can you paste the whole stacktrace? The top part with the exception name is missing.

Comment: @AlexanderHoffmann this stacktrace from xml design

Comment: The top part is missing. Does it say at the beginning someting about a `InflateException` or is it another exception?

Comment: Added full stacktrace when app runs

Comment: What's the Theme you're using when inflating this?

Comment: Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar

Answer (score 1):

I've created a fresh new app using the Empty Activity Template. Then I went to the almost empty `main_activity.xml` and pasted your BottomSheet.

I added your dependency to build.gradle.

I fixed the missing things:

1. constrains so the COnstraintLayout doesn't scream at me.
2. Colors, I picked random colors that come with Android.
3. Menu: you didn't supply this one, but I have the impression this is where your problem *could be*. Mine is empty, as I don't know what's in yours.
4. Theme: I changed the default from the template (DayNight) to Light.

And... it runs.

So, I'd start from this empty project, adding your bits one by one until you figure out what is crashing your inflation process.

#### Why do I think your menu is involved?

If you look at your stacktrace, the BottomNavigationView is calling its constructor `init()` and part of this involves inflating the menu items:

```
    at NavigationBarItemView.<init>(NavigationBarItemView.java:107)
    at BottomNavigationItemView.<init>(BottomNavigationItemView.java:34)
    at BottomNavigationMenuView.createNavigationBarItemView(BottomNavigationMenuView.java:197)
    at NavigationBarMenuView.getNewItem(NavigationBarMenuView.java:492)
    at NavigationBarMenuView.buildMenuView(NavigationBarMenuView.java:421)
    at.NavigationBarPresenter.updateMenuView(NavigationBarPresenter.java:72)
    at NavigationBarView.inflateMenu(NavigationBarView.java:358)
    at NavigationBarView.<init>(NavigationBarView.java:226)
```

Here's my sample project running:

[image: Image of Android Studio showing various XML and build files, and an emulator showing the sample running]

Comment: I have added zoom sdk, in that aar file this material dependency is added
`dependencies.add("default","com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0")`.
is that affect on app?

Answer (score 1):

If you are still facing this issue, it is probably being caused due to a custom implementation of an older version of [`design_bottom_navigation_item.xml`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/bottomnavigation/res/layout/design_bottom_navigation_item.xml) file either in your codebase or in the SDK. This file was updated in version `1.3.0` and again in `1.4.0` of Material Component Library. Overriding it with an incompatible version will cause the app to crash.